# Sorting number in command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

What I want is if I enter any number with space delimited, it will sort it in ascending order. I have this in my bash created file.

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
else 
   printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n 
fi
```

Basically what id does above is if the user enter a non numeric it will display an error else will sort the numbers.

So if I enter in command: $: sh sort.sh 12 0 13. This will order it out to

0

12

13

Now my problem is I don't want it in a new line, instead I want it in a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` is a line-based tool, so you can't remove the linefeeds before you call it. You can however replace them with spaces once the data is sorted, for example with `tr` :

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
   echo "error: Not a number" >&2; exit 1
else 
   printf "%s\n" $@ | sort -n | tr '\n' ' '
fi
```

Comment: hi, when I tried that it showing an extra character "%". -1, 0 12 13 %.

Comment: Weird, I tried it and it worked fine for me with 12 0 13

Comment: i run it like this: sh sort.sh 12 0 -1, 13. output was -1, 0 12 13 %

Comment: With `-1` I get "error: Not a number" due to your guard condition. The comma seems weird too and should make your regex reject it

Comment: im using mac os btw. Also I noticed if I put the comma beside the -1 it works. But on the other number it get the error not a number.

Comment: Makes sense, you only test the first parameter (`$1`) with your regex, and `sort` doesn't care about commas, minus signs and such (alphanumeric search by default).

Comment: oh you're right. what can i use on my if statement to check all arguments not just the first one. please help.

Comment: That calls for another question. I think your current question (how to get the output on a single line) was answered there. But I guess you could test `$@` against a regex such as `[0-9 ]+`, or `[0-9 -]+` if you want to accept minus signs

Comment: i got it to work now. still thank you for the insights